# Creating/Managing millions of Vertex Tree in Neo4j 3.0.4

Tags: neo4j, tree, database-performance

I'm doing some stuff with my University and I've been asked to create a system that builds Complete Trees with millions of nodes (1 or 2 million at least).
I was trying to create the Tree with a Load CSV Using a periodic commit and it worked well with the creation of just Nodes (70000 ms on a general purpose Notebook :P ). When I tried the same with the Edges, it didn't scale as well.

```
Using periodic commit LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Archi.csv' AS line 
Merge (:Vertex {name:line.from})<-[:EDGE {attr1: toFloat(line.attr1), attr2:toFloat(line.attr2), attr3: toFloat(line.attr3), attr4: toFloat(line.attr4), attr5: toFloat(line.attr5)}]-(:Vertex {name:line.to})
```

I need to guarantee that a Tree is generated in no more than 5 minutes.

Is there a Faster method that can return such a performances?

P.S. : The task doesn't expect to use Neo4j, but just a Database (either SQL or NoSQL), but I found out this NoSQL Graph DB and I thought would be nice to implement with Neo4j as the graph data structure is given for free.

P.P.S : I'm using Cypher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read up on MERGE in the developer documentation again, to make sure you understand exactly what it's doing.

A few things in particular to be aware of...

If the pattern you are merging does not exist, all elements of the pattern will be merged, which could result in duplicate :Vertex nodes being created. If your :Vertexes are supposed to be in the database already, and if there are no relationships yet, and if you are sure that no relationship repeats itself in your CSV, I strongly urge you to MATCH on the start and end nodes, and then CREATE the relationship between them instead of the MERGE. Remember that doing a MERGE with a relationship with many attributes means it will try to match on that first, so as the number of relationships grow between nodes, there will be an increasing number of comparisons, which will slow your query down further. CREATE is a better choice if you know that no relationship will be duplicated, and if you are sure those relationships don't exist yet.

I also urge you to create an index on :Vertex(name), as that will significantly help matching on end nodes.

Comment: As first, thanks for the help. I have one question that maybe will make you laugh .-. : How schema indexes works and how they can improve my queries?

Comment: Here's the [schema section](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypher-schema) in the developer documentation. Typically you'll create either a unique constraint or a schema index on a property of nodes with specific labels to improve performance when looking up nodes with that label by that property. By creating an index on :Vertex(name), lookups by :Vertex nodes by name (such as when matching to these nodes in order to create a relationship between them) use the index under the hood to make the lookup fast. Otherwise it has to scan all :Vertex nodes by the name property.

Comment: What about the super importer method? The documentation says that this tool is what you need for Huge Dataset structured as CSV, but I can't find this tool. Tool is located in "path/to/neo4j/bin/neo4j-import", says the doc, but i can't manage to call it. I'm using neo4j 3.0.4